# How to not immediately refresh after user input curses

Tags: python, terminal, user-input, curses

I am writing a DoodleJump game for the terminal in Python with curses. I use `getch()` to get the user input to know in which direction the character should move. When I get the user input my environment gets updated simultaneously but I want that it just keeps on moving and not update when I get the user input.
Does anybody know how I can achieve this? I tried using `nodelay()` but that still doesn't cut it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

please try with:

```
time.sleep(seconds)
```

This will wait the seconds you want before continue.

Sources:

https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-time-sleep-pause-wait-sleep-stop-your-code/

Hope it help, have a nice day,

David.

Comment: thank you for answering but I'm aware of the sleep function but that isn't really what I'm looking for. I need something that is implemtented by the curses library to fix this properly or I'll have to introduce some multithreading .

Comment: Im sorry I think the way I asked the question was wrong. I want to let the level run on its own and when I get user input I want to update the player position without the background moving faster bc of the input

Answer (score 0):

curses refreshes the window associated with [`getch`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.getch).  You could prevent refreshes (or hide them) by turning off `echo`, and using a window that won't have changes made to it (even one that you create just for that purpose).

Comment: The thing is that I need the refreshed but only for the player not the environment. But I don't know how to do this without multithreading